# In PHP, is it possible to set a variable name using a string?

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns, optimization

I have a piece of code like

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$story = $_POST['story'];
$imgurl = $_POST['imgurl'];
$thisAction = $_POST['thisAction'];
```

As you can see, the variable names I'm using are equal to the keys of the `$_POST` array. Is it possible to accomplish the above with a loop?

Comment: it's called "variable variables", and please don't go there. what's wrong with using $_POST['id']?

Comment: @MarcB I don't want to have to use `$_POST['id']` multiple times because that would be inefficient. Better to save a copy of the value returned by it.

Comment: and other than saving a few characters while tyipng, how would it be more efficient to have to replicate `$id` everywhere?

Comment: Assign it once to a variable `$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;` and be done with it. Not sure how that would be more efficient, though. edit: slow again...

Comment: @MarcB If you do `$_POST['id']` then there are operations involved in taking key and converting it to a value. That's how maps work.

Comment: you're waaaaaaay overoptimizing. the few microseconds you're going to save could be better spent optimizing real problems,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

or using [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
extract($_POST);
```

But please be aware that **doing this will introduce a potential security hole**.

It's in fact like [simulating PHP's `register_globals` directive, which introduces lots of security issues.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

---

You could assign a subset of `$_POST` variables, this is a much safer way:

```
$keys = array('id', 'name', 'story', 'imgurl', 'thisAction');
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $$key = $_POST[$key];
}
```

or using `extract`:

```
$whitelisted = array_intersect_key($_POST, array('id', 'name', 'story', 'imgurl', 'thisAction')); 
extract($whitelisted);
```

Comment: Alternative/Additional addition could be to pass `EXTR_SKIP` to extract.